# comparing a column from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` and I would like to show the result of a search where I will check if in `TABLE1` the column named `name` contains `xyz`, and the after it should compare with `TABLE2` `AUDITED_ID` field and show the field from `TABLE2` where the `TABLE2`  `AUDITED_ID` field will be equal with the Table 1 ID field where TABLE1 ID field get a name column as well and it should contain `xyz`.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT AUDITED_ID FROM TABLE2
WHERE
TABLE1.NAME LIKE '%XYZ%'
AND 
TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.AUDITED_ID;
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT ID FROM DOMAINS
WHERE NAME LIKE '%GGV%'
UNION
SELECT AUDITED_ENTITY_ID FROM AUDIT_LOGS
WHERE
DOMAINS.ID = AUDIT_LOGS.AUDITED_ENTITY_ID;
```

I have tried in several ways but it is not working, I always got an error message, any idea how should I start?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and needed result?

Comment: you should use an Inner Join with a Where condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an INNER JOIN to join the both tables first on the ID - This will remove your unwanted IDs from the result set

Then use a WHERE condition to check for you condition

```
SELECT 
     t1.ID ,

     -- you can select other columns from t1 and t2 here
     t2.AUDITED_ID ,
     t1.NAME

FROM TABLE1 t1

INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.AUDITED_ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.NAME LIKE '%XYZ%'
```